# Function to firebase store 2-5 images, then getDownloadURL all URLS => [ ] (array), and set to react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, promise

This function currently does not work as intended. It stores images perfectly, but getDownloadURL is not able to put ALL Image URLs into an array [].

This array of urls e.g. [1.png, 2.png, 3.png] is needed to set to State, to then be integrated into product details, and have Amazon Product page like functionality. A product with multiple pictures.

I've experimented with

Promises.all
async await
Searching thru repos of similar problems

But perhaps things are in the wrong order when I try it.

The flow should be 1) Complete all uploads, 2) Get all URLs in [], 3) Set to State.

We'll remember any assistance given, Ad Astra.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const promises = [];
        preproductThumbnail.map(async (image) => {
            const uploadTask = storage().ref(`prodimages/${image.name}`).put(image);
            await promises.push(uploadTask);
           
                uploadTask.on("state_changed",(snapshot) => {const progress =(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) *100; console.log(progress);},(err) => {setError(err.message);},
                    // ALL FILES UPLOADED NEED TO BE FINISHED BEFORE MOVING AHEAD
                    () => {
                        storage()
                            .ref("prodimages")
                            .child(image.name)
                            .getDownloadURL() // 2 images
                            // console.log("PRODTHUMB1", productThumbnail)

                                // put an array in here, then change fetch function on Productpage
                                .then((productThumbnail) => {
                                setProductThumbnail((prevState) => [...prevState,productThumbnail,])

                                console.log("PRODTHUMB2", productThumbnail);
                                //put promises.all here
                                  },  resetForm());
                    }
                );
        });
        // Promise.all(promises)
        //     // .then(() => alert("All images uploaded"))
        //     .catch((err) => console.log(err));

        console.log("preprod2: ", preproductThumbnail);
        console.log("prod2", productThumbnail);
    };
```

Comment: I don't see you using progress apart from logging it. Do you really need to track progress?

Comment: Hey thanks for commenting, I thought progress might somehow ensure all files were uploading before moving on to the next action. But that is not the case. Maybe not unless I use "await" somewhere in there.

Comment: It's possible I could use await progress of all files somehow, so that I can await getDownloadURL of all images, and set to productThumbnail hook, but yeah we havent been successful